# extract the certain part of a string

Tags: javascript

I have a below string i need to extract certain part of the string.

```
 input :  'response:"The check has enabled" '
    
 output:  The check has enabled
```

Is there any better way, i have achieved with the below snippet.

```js
let string = 'response:"The check has enabled" '
let output = string.replace(
  `response:"`,
  ""
)

output = output.substring(0, output.length - 2);

console.log(output)
```

Comment: It seems like you are trying to convert a JSON response to a string. If you use the JSON version you don't need all of the extra functions.

Comment: The problem is i am getting the response as like this as a string, so thats why

Comment: @imvain2 It's not JSON - if it was JSON, it'd be `"response":`, but it's `response:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match text between `"`s:

```js
const string = 'response:"The check has enabled" '
const output = string.match(/(?<=")[^"]+(?=")/)[0];
console.log(output)
```

If you control the API that creates the `string` that needs to be parsed, it would be far better to change it so that it gives you JSON instead, and then you can use `JSON.parse` on it, and just access the `.response` property of the object.